# Configuring splash screen for installer using install4j

Tags: install4j, splash-screen

How we can configure splash screen for Installer. As I know there is option to configure splash during launching the app. But I want to have splash screen just after the installer is launched. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in install4j as of install4j 6.0.3.